# The Sum of people that have same age in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

I'm taking a SQL class and I need help with a question.

I have the following table on a phpmyadmin server

```
patient (id, age)
```

with a total of 100 patients

I'm told to find the sum of people that have same age using SQL.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(age) 
FROM patient 
HAVING (COUNT(age) > 1);
```

but it returns 100 as a result and when I did this query and found the number of patients who have the same age for each age and calculated the count manually I found 78 and I checked it manually and it's indeed 78.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM patient 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database. It's a web application for querying and managing a MySQL database.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of people with the same age"? People aren't numbers, you can't sum them.

Comment: If the ages are `10, 20, 10, 30, 20` is that 4 people because there are 2 with age 10 and 2 with age 20?

Comment: i mean the total number of patients who have the same age . its 78 ,,,, and there 3 with an age of 20 and 3 with an age of 28 and so on and the total number is 78 ( got it manually ) i need a querry so as i can get the total number

Comment: It would be far more helpful if instead of transferring the whole problem from your task into your question, you show the smallest sample data that demonstrates the edge cases of the problem, perhaps 5-10 rows, and showed the expected output from that. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a subquery that gets the counts of people with each age. Then filter this to counts more than 1 so it's just people with the same age.

Then in the main query you use `SUM()` to add all these counts together, to get the total number of patients.

```
SELECT SUM(count)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM patient
    GROUP BY age
    HAVING count > 1
) AS x
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select age, count(*) from patient group by age;
```

Comment: please always write some explanation to your code

Comment: This doesn't get the total.